# ZeroMQ socket pushing to a lightweight HTML5 client

Tags: javascript, html, sockets, zeromq, publish-subscribe

My data collection system publishes data to a ZeroMQ socket.

I was hoping to graph the streaming data in a client application. I don't have a lot of experience with GUI design, so decided to opt for building a HTML5 client. A lot of the solutions I have read up involves putting in additional layers to get everything to work: such as interposing a web server to subscribe to the socket and then generate the HTML to serve to the user.

**A:** What is the easiest and most lightweight way to push streaming data from the ZeroMQ socket directly into a HTML5 client with the least amount of additional code? A code example would be extremely helpful.

**B:** Is there a javascript file that be loaded by the HTML5 page that will allow it to pick up the data from the ZeroMQ socket?

**C:** If that's not the possibility, what is the next simplest approach that actually does allow the data from the socket to be pushed into a HTML5 page?

Here's a mockup of the publisher.

```
# server.py
import zmq
from random import randrange
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
socket.bind("tcp://*:7770")
for i in range(1000):
    temperature = randrange(-80, 135)
    socket.send_string("%i" % (temperature))
```

Comment: I think you need websockets

Comment: I read about this. But I have other clients (non-GUI) that subscribe to the ZeroMQ socket. Am I forced to put in a webserver then?

Comment: When your client receives the message, it parses the message to its taste. In case of a web socket server (node, for example), you'd parse the message you received and then write to the web socket, effectively notifying people using browsers. You write proxies that consume messages sent over ZMQ PUB/SUB. How and what those proxies do - that's up to you to decide and implement, is it not? There's no way to use ZMQ and directly feed the browser without the middle-man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case one has to integrate ZeroMQ signalling / messaging infrastructure,
including such infrastructure nodes, where javascript code can and has to run, the best place to start

### check the available javascript bindings as published on ZeroMQ site:

There are two available in javascript segment published on ZeroMQ directly:
- first: http://zeromq.org/bindings:node-js
- another: http://zeromq.org/bindings:javascript

also kindly review the rightmost column with other available ZeroMQ bindings, that are ready for wider integration needs.

### plus, besides the ZeroMQ-sockets, there is also another option:

for extended requirements coverage, the more recent ZeroMQ API provides tools for direct access to underlying sockets, via it's file descriptor. In such a case, the remote end may mirror ( implement ) the required ZeroMQ-protocol ( as per the published specification document ) in a form of a narrow-purpose fully-functional proxy to otherwise standard ZeroMQ socket protocol service.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I did check out the zeromq site but did not find anything minimal enough for my taste. Node is a server framework. The other uses Flash.

Comment: Your direction is ruled by the choice of the code-execution environment. ECMAScript / ActionScript capable client may get inspired from porting Flex ( javascript ) binding to such target system deployment. The decision is in your hands.